# elfinder with multiple users

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, elfinder

I'm using Symfony 2.3, [FMElfinderBundle](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle) and [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle). Both bundles works fine. My question relates to how to connect both bundles. When user register then I want to create directory for him and tell FMElfinderBundle to use that directory for that user. Another user will have another directory etc.

I know that FMElfinderBundle can have multiple roots in config.yml

```
fm_elfinder:
    locale: %locale%
    editor: ckeditor # other choices are tinymce or simple
    showhidden: false # defaults to false
    fullscreen: true # defaults true, applies to simple and ckeditor editors
    connector:
        debug: false # defaults to false
        roots:       # at least one root must be defined
            uploads:
                driver: LocalFileSystem
                path: uploads
                upload_allow: ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg']
                upload_deny: ['all']
                upload_max_size: 2M
```

How can I dynamically assign users to directories with all permissions? Any idea? What is the best solution for that? Maybe another file manager?

Answer (score 0):

may be its too late for answer, but its better late than never :), and probably posting answer here, will help someone else too.
You can check bundle's 2.0 branch for basic user integration, or override configuration service, with own logic, to provide specific, user depended (and not only) configuration for the bundle.